# Insert persistence record in DB where two table are seprate

Tags: hibernate, struts

I am using `struts` and `hibernate`. i am trying to insert data in two table which are independent. if first table insertions create any error than i can not able to insert second table data and vice-versa. i want to do like this. how can i do this?

code

```
public String create() {
    getDaoFactory().instantiateDAO(daoClass).saveOrUpdate(entity);
    getDaoFactory().getMatchPredictionOptionLevel2().saveOrUpdate(
                    optionLevel2);
   return SUCCESS:

}

public T saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
        try {
            getSessionTx().save(entity);
            commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            getSession().close();
        }
        return entity;
    }

public Session getSessionTx() {
        System.out.println("In Get Sassion Method getSessionTx");
        if (this.session == null)
            this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        this.session.beginTransaction();
        return this.session;
    }
```

Comment: can anyone tell me solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is what `Transactions` has been made for.

For Instance:

```
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();//<==Creade Session from SessionFactory

            tx = session.beginTransaction();//<==== Start Transacton
            tx.setTimeout(5);
            //doSomething(session); if one of the queries fail to insert it goes to catch 
            tx.commit();

        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            try{
                tx.rollback();//<=== you'll be rolling back the previous inserting value in case if one failed to insert
            }catch(RuntimeException rbe){
                log.error("Couldn’t roll back transaction", rbe);
            }
            throw e;
        }finally{
            if(session!=null){
                session.close();
            }
```

Read more about it [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Transaction.html).

Comment: actually for insertion i have use seprate mothod for that. for individualy inseriton i have rollback but if first table query successfully inserted and it create error in second table then first table entry is not roll back

Comment: @CHiRAG your code is broken 1. String should return a value, 2. what is getSessionTx() ?

Comment: see i have add return type, and actually my function is have other logic so i have add important code for that only

Comment: `getSessionTx()` its a custome method for create session and initilize to transaction